# MySql - How to get rid of the No Data : Zero Rows Fetched

Tags: mysql

So i have written this small stored function which is supposed to return the cost of a juiceorder to me. However, i am having some trouble figuring out why specifically it isnt working. Any help would be appreciated

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `juiceOrderCost`(p_id INT) RETURNS double
BEGIN
DECLARE cost DOUBLE;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE numRows INT;
DECLARE numDone INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE cup_id INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR for
    SELECT cupId FROM hasJuice WHERE orderID = p_id;

OPEN myCursor;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO numRows;

FETCH myCursor INTO cup_id;
WHILE numDone <= numRows DO

SET cost =  cost + juiceCupCost(cup_id);

FETCH myCursor INTO cup_id;

SET numDone = numDone + 1;

END WHILE;

CLOSE myCursor;
```

RETURN cost;
END

Comment: why a cursor. where is juiceCupCost. Where have you established your `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;` and read loop

Comment: often times people use cursors because they like to think procedurally and are not in the set and relation mindset yet. Cursors run like dogs. Shoot for joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: Mostly used a cursor because its really the only solution i could think of. I am a very novice beginner to say the least. I have not established that. juiceCupCost is a function in the same database. That one works fine. given a cupID, it gives me the cost of that cupId. And i have no idea what you meant by read loop/.

Comment: Basically what i want to do is just find rows corresponding to a certain OrderId. Read the cupId specified by that orderId. Run the juiceCupCost on that CupId. Add the cost of all the cups and print that out. I am sure there is a better way to do it than the one i have outlined but i cant seem to think of it. Would love some ideas.

Comment: @Drew   -- Do you have any ideas regarding how i could possibly achieve what i just outlined using Joins and Aggregate. I understand that well enough but i can't seem to think of how i would be able to apply that here.

Comment: I would need to know your schema. But something [Like This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33428343/1816093) I wrote up an hour ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND`
Visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/condition-handling.html